# Auto fill login dialog username using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk

Is it possible to auto fill the Username text field of the Facebook login dialog using the SDK (specifically, Facebook Unity SDK).

What I'm trying to do is to "remember" the last users user name to log in and then auto fill the username box with that users name when they start the app again to reduce the amount of data entry they would need to enter at app start.

I have Single Sign-on enabled, but I would like to implement this so people who do not have the Facebook app installed only need to enter their password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no support for that.

Source: I work on the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Should have been a comment instead

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why would you say this is not an answer? This is a direct answer to their question of "is it possible". It's neither a critique nor a request for clarification.

Comment: I was looking for any supporting references towards your answer

Comment: There's no supporting documents because it's not supported, it's much like proving a negative.